# Import module stored in a cStringIO data structure vs. physical disk file

Tags: python, import, module

Is there a way to import a Python module stored in a cStringIO data structure vs. physical disk file?

It looks like "imp.load_compiled(name, pathname[, file])" is what I need, but the description of this method (and similar methods) has the following disclaimer:

Quote: "The file argument is the byte-compiled code file, open for reading in binary mode, from the beginning. It must currently be a real file object, not a user-defined class emulating a file." [1]

I tried using a cStringIO object vs. a real file object, but the help documentation is correct - only a real file object can be used.

Any ideas on why these modules would impose such a restriction or is this just an historical artifact?

Are there any techniques I can use to avoid this physical file requirement?

Thanks,
Malcolm

[1] http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_module

Comment: For those following this thread, I was trying to build a solution based on the imp module. Matt's solution below is much more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
import types
import sys

src = """
def hello(who):
    print 'hello', who
"""

def module_from_text(modulename, src):
    if modulename in sys.modules:
        module = sys.modules[modulename]
    else:
        module = sys.modules[modulename] = types.ModuleType(modulename)
    exec compile(src, '<no-file>', 'exec') in module.__dict__
    return module

module_from_text('flup', src)
import flup
flup.hello('world')
```

Which prints:

```
hello world
```

**EDIT**:

Evaluating code in this way treads nearish the realm of writing custom importers. It may be useful to look at [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/), and Doug Hellmann's [PyMOTW: Modules and Imports](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sys/imports.html).

Comment: Matt: 

I've been studying and experimenting with your code  and it works great.

Wonder if you can help me out with some of these questions:

1. Why don't I need to do anything with the module value returned by module_from_text()?

2. Why do I use module.__dict vs. globals(), locals() for the value of the exec statement's 'in' clause?

3. Are there any downsides to this approach as long as my src value comes from a trusted source?

Thank you,
Malcolm

Comment: @Malcolm: 1. You can do what you'd like with the returned value, but you don't need it because the module is now in `sys.modules`. 2. Because you want the code to exec in the namespace of the module (and put definitions and assignments in there); if you `exec`'d in some other namespace, the assignments wouldn't end up in the module. 3. Not sure. This is similar, I believe, to how the import internals work, but I may have left something important out (like exception handling). See the post body for a couple references.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your explanation and associated references helped answer my questions. Regards, Malcolm